# I have installed Python and it is giving error

Tags: python

I have intsalled python(3.11) in my local machine and trying to check the libraires from command prompt and getting error

[image]

Please advise the supporting command document

Thanks in advance

Comment: `pip list` is not python code.  Why are you trying to run a **terminal command** as python code?

Comment: The downvotes are probably related to the use of an image rather than text to show the code attempt and the error. While I did not downvote, I do find it frustrating that we can't find a way to properly communicate that an image is had to work with. Not the least of which is that in the event that an answer was provided, there would be no way to search for this problem in the future as the text of the issue and error are hidden in the image.

Answer (score 2):

You are inside the Python interpreter. Exit the interpreter with `CTRL + Z, Enter`. Then you can run the command successfully. Pip is a [package installer for Python](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/); it is not run inside the Python interpreter.